# How to invert a matrix that contains all-zero rows?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, linear-algebra

I am running [this algorithm](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00949659908811970), which computes the MLE of the matrix normal distribution.

One part of the algorithm requires computing the inverse of a matrix that contains all-zero rows. How can we solve this problem?

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, there exists no inverse of a singular matrix. Thus, the question is in which context is it used in the algorithm and whether a [generalized inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) or in particular, a [pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)  matrix can be used instead. However, this is rather a mathematical than a programming question.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific about the calculations you are performing? If you have to invert a zero matrix, there is likely something wrong with your program or the theory behind it. A square matrix is invertible if and only if its column vectors are linearly independent, or equivalently its determinant is nonzero.